# Linux Embedded board - Kernel Panic problems

Tags: firmware, linux, embedded

I need to duplicate an old embedded board based on a Yocto-based Linux.

I have bought a new board with the same part number and now I need to put the old software in the new board (the new board has only u-boot installed).

The original board has u-boot with few command list, so I had to dumped the memory by serial terminal.

I got some file in .txt with the internal memory data and I convert them in .bin with Linux `xxd -r` command and i put the data in my new board.

When I turn on my new board, the Linux kernel starts but it can't find the partition and stops to work and says:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

### OLD BOARD BOOT:

```
U-Boot 2009.01 (May 28 2011 - 03:25:24)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX25 at 398 MHz
Board: GEA_M6425 
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  64 MB
NAND:  Bad block table found at page 131008, version 0x01
Bad block table found at page 130944, version 0x01
256 MiB
NAND read: device 0 offset 0xc0000, size 0x40000
    262144 bytes read: OK
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
i2c_addr:chip address cycle fail(a1)
Net:   miiphy_register: non unique device name 'FEC0'
FEC0, FEC0
Version: 
Note:    
Auto-update from TFTP: trying update file 'prog.scr'
FEC: enable RMII gasket
Using FEC0 device
TFTP from server 192.168.140.12; our IP address is 192.168.140.30
Filename 'prog.scr'.
Load address: 0x81000000
Loading: *T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T 
Retry count exceeded; starting again
Can't load update file, aborting auto-update
Auto-update from NAND:
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x1000000, size 0x20
    32 bytes read: OK
No image found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  3  2  1  0 
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x100000, size 0x300000
    3145728 bytes read: OK
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 81000000 ...
    Image Name:   Linux-2.6.31-rc9
    Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
    Data Size:    2318824 Bytes =  2.2 MB
    Load Address: 80008000
    Entry Point:  80008000
    Verifying Checksum ... OK
    Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
Starting kernel ...
Uncompressing Linux....................................................................................................................................................... done, booting the kernel.
Linux version 2.6.31-rc9 (user@evelin) (gcc version 4.1.2) #1 PREEMPT Tue Sep 27 21:35:47 CEST 2011
CPU: ARM926EJ-S [41069264] revision 4 (ARMv5TEJ), cr=00053177
CPU: VIVT data cache, VIVT instruction cache
Machine: Freescale MX25 3-Stack Board
Ignoring unrecognised tag 0x54410008
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 16256
Kernel command line: console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=jffs2 video=mxcfb:320x240,16bpp,Var-QVGA
PID hash table entries: 256 (order: 8, 1024 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Memory: 64MB = 64MB total
Memory: 59916KB available (4264K code, 484K data, 124K init, 0K highmem)
NR_IRQS:272
MXC IRQ initialized
Clock input source is 24000000
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Calibrating delay loop... 199.06 BogoMIPS (lpj=995328)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
regulator: core version 0.5
NET: Registered protocol family 16
AIPS1 VA base: 0xfc000000
CPU is i.MX25 Revision 1.0
MXC GPIO hardware
rate 22166666
Using SDMA I.API
MXC DMA API initialized
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
MXC I2C driver
i2c-adapter i2c-0: ACK not received 
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
TCP reno registered
NET: Registered protocol family 1
Bus freq driver module loaded
usb: Host 2 host (serial) registered
usb: DR host (utmi) registered
JFFS2 version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
SGI XFS with security attributes, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
msgmni has been set to 117
alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
MXC Backlight Device mxc_lcdc_bl.0 Initialized.
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 40x30
mxc_sdc_fb mxc_sdc_fb.0: fb0: DISP0 BG fb device registered successfully.
mxc_sdc_fb mxc_sdc_fb.0: fb1: DISP0 FG fb device registered successfully.
Serial: MXC Internal UART driver
mxcintuart.0: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x43f90000 (irq = 45) is a Freescale i.MX
console [ttymxc0] enabled
mxcintuart.1: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x43f94000 (irq = 32) is a Freescale i.MX
mxcintuart.2: ttymxc2 at MMIO 0x5000c000 (irq = 18) is a Freescale i.MX
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
Freescale FlexCAN Driver 
FEC Ethernet Driver
fec_enet_mii_bus: probed
IEEE1588: ptp-timer is unavailable
console [netcon0] enabled
netconsole: network logging started
MXC MTD nand Driver 2.5
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x20, Chip ID: 0xaa (ST Micro NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit)
Searching for RedBoot partition table in NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit at offset 0xff60000
No RedBoot partition table detected in NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "nand.bootloader"
0x000000100000-0x000000400000 : "nand.kernel"
0x000000400000-0x00000fc00000 : "nand.rootfs"
0x00000fc00000-0x00000fd00000 : "nand.configure"
0x00000fd00000-0x000010000000 : "nand.userfs"
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: irq 35, io base 0x53ff4400
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: irq 37, io base 0x53ff4000
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
usb usb2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
i.MX ADC at 0x50030000 irq 46
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
mxsdhci: MXC Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
mxsdhci: MXC SDHCI Controller Driver. 
mmc0: SDHCI detect irq 161 irq 9 INTERNAL DMA
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.20.
regulator: Unable to get requested regulator: VDDIO
regulator: Unable to get requested regulator: VDDA
regulator: Unable to get requested regulator: VDDD
sgtl5000-i2c 0-000a: SGTL5000 revision 17
No device for DAI imx-ssi-1-0
No device for DAI imx-ssi-1-1
No device for DAI imx-ssi-2-0
No device for DAI imx-ssi-2-1
DMA Sound Buffers Allocated:UseIram=0 buf->addr=83ab0000 buf->area=fde56000 size=65536
DMA Sound Buffers Allocated:UseIram=0 buf->addr=83ac0000 buf->area=fde66000 size=65536
asoc: SGTL5000 <-> imx-ssi-1-0 mapping ok
ALSA device list:
    #0: imx-3stack (SGTL5000)
oprofile: using timer interrupt.
TCP cubic registered
NET: Registered protocol family 17
can: controller area network core (rev 20090105 abi 8)
NET: Registered protocol family 29
can: raw protocol (rev 20090105)
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
Static Power Management for Freescale i.MX25
on-off key pressed
input: imx_adc_ts as /class/input/input0
i.MX ADC input touchscreen loaded.
JFFS2 doesn't use OOB.
VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) on device 31:2.
Freeing init memory: 124K

init started: BusyBox v1.15.3 (2011-09-27 21:22:33 CEST)
starting pid 898, tty '': '/etc/init.d/rcS'
Initializing mdev dynamic device directory ... done
eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=0:00, irq=-1)

can0 bitrate: 175000
dropbear already configured
Starting Dropbear SSH server: dropbear.
ts already configured

starting pid 939, tty '/dev/ttymxc0': '-/bin/sh'

BusyBox v1.15.3 (2011-09-27 21:22:33 CEST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/ #
```

### NEW BOARD BOOT:

```
U-Boot 2009.01-dirty (Nov 15 2013 - 17:55:59)
CPU:   Freescale i.MX25 at 398 MHz
Board: GEA_M6425 
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  64 MB
NAND:  Bad block table not found for chip 0
Bad block table not found for chip 0
Bad block table written to 0x0ffe0000, version 0x01
Bad block table written to 0x0ffc0000, version 0x01
256 MiB
Use default panel_info values
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
i2c_addr:chip address cycle fail(a1)
Net:   FEC0
Version: 
Note:    
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  3  2  1  0 
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x100000, size 0x300000
    3145728 bytes read: OK
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 81000000 ...
    Image Name:   Linux-2.6.31-rc9
    Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
    Data Size:    2318824 Bytes =  2.2 MB
    Load Address: 80008000
    Entry Point:  80008000
    Verifying Checksum ... OK
    Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
Starting kernel ...
Uncompressing Linux....................................................................................................................................................... done, booting the kernel.
Linux version 2.6.31-rc9 (user@evelin) (gcc version 4.1.2) #1 PREEMPT Tue Sep 27 21:35:47 CEST 2011
CPU: ARM926EJ-S [41069264] revision 4 (ARMv5TEJ), cr=00053177
CPU: VIVT data cache, VIVT instruction cache
Machine: Freescale MX25 3-Stack Board
Ignoring unrecognised tag 0x54410008
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 16256
Kernel command line: console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=jffs2 video=mxcfb:800x480,16bpp,Amp-WD
PID hash table entries: 256 (order: 8, 1024 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Memory: 64MB = 64MB total
Memory: 59916KB available (4264K code, 484K data, 124K init, 0K highmem)
NR_IRQS:272
MXC IRQ initialized
Clock input source is 24000000
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Calibrating delay loop... 199.06 BogoMIPS (lpj=995328)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
regulator: core version 0.5
NET: Registered protocol family 16
AIPS1 VA base: 0xfc000000
CPU is i.MX25 Revision 1.0
MXC GPIO hardware
rate 22166666
Using SDMA I.API
MXC DMA API initialized
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
MXC I2C driver
i2c-adapter i2c-0: ACK not received 
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
TCP reno registered
NET: Registered protocol family 1
Bus freq driver module loaded
usb: Host 2 host (serial) registered
usb: DR host (utmi) registered
JFFS2 version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
SGI XFS with security attributes, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
msgmni has been set to 117
alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
MXC Backlight Device mxc_lcdc_bl.0 Initialized.
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x30
mxc_sdc_fb mxc_sdc_fb.0: fb0: DISP0 BG fb device registered successfully.
mxc_sdc_fb mxc_sdc_fb.0: fb1: DISP0 FG fb device registered successfully.
Serial: MXC Internal UART driver
mxcintuart.0: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x43f90000 (irq = 45) is a Freescale i.MX
console [ttymxc0] enabled
mxcintuart.1: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x43f94000 (irq = 32) is a Freescale i.MX
mxcintuart.2: ttymxc2 at MMIO 0x5000c000 (irq = 18) is a Freescale i.MX
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
Freescale FlexCAN Driver 
FEC Ethernet Driver
fec_enet_mii_bus: probed
IEEE1588: ptp-timer is unavailable
console [netcon0] enabled
netconsole: network logging started
MXC MTD nand Driver 2.5
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x2c, Chip ID: 0xaa (Micron NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit)
Unrecognized NAND Flash device.
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: irq 35, io base 0x53ff4400
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: irq 37, io base 0x53ff4000
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.1: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
usb usb2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
i.MX ADC at 0x50030000 irq 46
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
mxsdhci: MXC Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
mxsdhci: MXC SDHCI Controller Driver. 
mmc0: SDHCI detect irq 161 irq 9 INTERNAL DMA
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.20.
regulator: Unable to get requested regulator: VDDIO
regulator: Unable to get requested regulator: VDDA
regulator: Unable to get requested regulator: VDDD
sgtl5000-i2c 0-000a: SGTL5000 revision 17
No device for DAI imx-ssi-1-0
No device for DAI imx-ssi-1-1
No device for DAI imx-ssi-2-0
No device for DAI imx-ssi-2-1
DMA Sound Buffers Allocated:UseIram=0 buf->addr=83a90000 buf->area=fdf82000 size=65536
DMA Sound Buffers Allocated:UseIram=0 buf->addr=83aa0000 buf->area=fdf92000 size=65536
asoc: SGTL5000 <-> imx-ssi-1-0 mapping ok
ALSA device list:
    #0: imx-3stack (SGTL5000)
oprofile: using timer interrupt.
TCP cubic registered
NET: Registered protocol family 17
can: controller area network core (rev 20090105 abi 8)
NET: Registered protocol family 29
can: raw protocol (rev 20090105)
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
Static Power Management for Freescale i.MX25
on-off key pressed
input: imx_adc_ts as /class/input/input0
i.MX ADC input touchscreen loaded.
Root-NFS: No NFS server available, giving up.
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
List of all partitions:
No filesystem could mount root, tried:  jffs2
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

Can you help me to understand the problem?

---

These are the output of file command:

```
nand_bootloader_0x0000000-0x00FFFFF.bin: FoxPro FPT, blocks size 0, next free block index 1778450666

nand_kernel_0x0100000-0x03FFFFF.bin: u-boot legacy uImage, Linux-2.6.31-rc9, Linux/ARM, OS Kernel Image (Not compressed), 2318824 bytes, Tue Sep 27 21:36:01 2011, Load Address: 0x80008000, Entry Point: 0x80008000, Header CRC: 0x230C882F, Data CRC: 0xCD73A8A7

nand_rootfs_1_0x0400000-0x06FFFFF.bin: AIX core file fulldump 32-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377 64-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377


nand_rootfs_2_0x0700000-0x09FFFFF.bin: Linux jffs2 filesystem data little endian

nand_rootfs_3_0x0A00000-0x0EFFFFF.bin: AIX core file fulldump 32-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377 64-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377

nand_rootfs_4_0x0F00000-0x13FFFFF.bin: AIX core file fulldump 32-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377 64-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377

nand_rootfs_5_0x1400000-0x18FFFFF.bin: AIX core file fulldump 32-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377 64-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377

nand_rootfs_6_0x1900000-0x1DFFFFF.bin: AIX core file fulldump 32-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377 64-bit, \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377


nand_rootfs_7_0x1E00000-0x22FFFFF.bin: Linux jffs2 filesystem data little endia

nand_configure_0xFC00000-0xFCFFFFF.bin: u-boot legacy uImage, Linux-2.6.31-rc9-gec38174-dirty, Linux/ARM, OS Kernel Image (Not compressed), 2321092 bytes, Fri Oct  8 23:26:48 2010, Load Address: 0x80008000, Entry Point: 0x80008000, Header CRC: 0xE1994975, Data CRC: 0x55F17506

nand_userfs_0xFD00000-0xFFFFFFF.bin: data
```

(rootfs is split into 7 files).

UPDATES:

Hi, I made a contiguous file with your command. Now I set the NFS server on my linux PC (in `/etc/exports` file I put the string `/srv myip/my mask(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash`) and save. I put the `nand_rootfs.bin` file in folder `/srv` and after i tried to setup UBOOT in my board. This is the `printenv` command of my Uboot:

```
bootdelay=3
baudrate=115200
loadaddr=0x81000000
netdev=eth0
ethprime=fec
bootargs_nand=console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=jffs2 video=
mxcfb:320x240,16bpp,Var-QVGA
bootcmd_nand=nand read 81000000 100000 300000; bootm 81000000
bootcmd_tftp=tftp uImage; bootm
mirror_update=enable
tftp_timeout=6000
tftp_retry=20
checksum_control=false
ethact=FEC0
filesize=27B84
fileaddr=80800000
offset=80000
GEA_SN=A54673
fec_addr=9C:53:CD:05:5E:C2
fecaddr=9C:53:CD:05:5E:C2
ethaddr=9C:53:CD:05:5E:C2
splashload=nand read 80800000 c0000 40000
splashimage=80800000
lcd_name=Var-QVGA
splashpos=0,0
bootcmd=run bootcmd_nand
bootargs=console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw rootfstype=jff2 video=mxcfb:320x240,16bpp,Var-QVGA mtdparts=nand:1M(nand.bootloader),3M(nand.kernel),-(rootfs)
ipaddr=192.168.11.60
serverip=192.168.11.64
bootargs_nfs=console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw ip=$(ipaddr) nfsroot=$(serverip):/srv/nand_rootfs.bin rootfstype=jff2 video=mxcfb:320x240,16bpp,Var-QVGA

Environment size: 991/262140 bytes
```

When I run the command:

```
run bootargs_nfs
```

I get:

```
Unknown command 'console=ttymxc0,115200' - try 'help'
```

Is this procedure correct ? I modify the `bootargs_nfs` with command:

```
setenv 'bootargs_nfs console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw ip=$(ipaddr) nfsroot=$(serverip):/srv/nand_rootfs.bin rootfstype=jff2 video=mxcfb:320x240,16bpp,Var-QVGA'
```

Comment: Okay, cool. I think the rootfs files can probably be joined into a single file. From what I saw the addresses are adjacent. In theory something along the lines of `cat nand_rootfs_{1..7}_*.bin > nand_rootfs.bin` should work and give you one contiguous `nand_rootfs.bin` file. After that it should be possible to mount it on a system with jffs2 support. If we'd manage that, that'd be the first step toward making it available via NFS. With the command I am assuming there are only those `*.bin` files ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not (yet) an expert, but since I work in embedded software now I'd guess that this is your problem:

### Old:

```
MXC MTD nand Driver 2.5
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x20, Chip ID: 0xaa (ST Micro NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit)
Searching for RedBoot partition table in NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit at offset 0xff60000
No RedBoot partition table detected in NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "nand.bootloader"
0x000000100000-0x000000400000 : "nand.kernel"
0x000000400000-0x00000fc00000 : "nand.rootfs"
0x00000fc00000-0x00000fd00000 : "nand.configure"
0x00000fd00000-0x000010000000 : "nand.userfs"
```

### New:

```
MXC MTD nand Driver 2.5
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x2c, Chip ID: 0xaa (Micron NAND 256MiB 1,8V 8-bit)
Unrecognized NAND Flash device.
```

Long story short, you'll need something that your kernel will recognize. The NAND components are from different vendors, so while the boards may be the same to the manufacturer, they differ in details that matter to your older kernel.

Also, your kernel command line (typically taken from the U-Boot environment) differs between the two boots.

---

However, I would reckon there's at least a way to get this to boot as follows:

- from the U-Boot environment (basically you hit a key during the `Hit any key to stop autoboot:` prompt) you find out what your new board does to find the NFS server
- set up a local DHCP server
- make sure to make the root FS from your old board available under the expected path
- boot - as you did now - and you should get a system up and running on an NFS root FS

While this doesn't solve the problem of modifying your existing kernel to fully boot off the NAND on the new board, it will allow you to tinker further with the new boot which the kernel panic *currently* prevents you from doing.

It's also possible that modifying something in the U-Boot environment will get you further, but *this* is what I'd do at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry if i reply you only now but i had personal problems last weeks :(. I would like try your solution by NFS but i don't have the imagine files but only .bin.
I read data from the old device and save it in .bin file (i used nand read command from U-boot). I have these files now:
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : bootloader.bin
0x000000100000-0x000000400000 : kernel.bin
0x000000400000-0x00000fc00000 : rootfs.bin
0x00000fc00000-0x00000fd00000 : configure.bin
0x00000fd00000-0x000010000000 : userfs.bin I need to start an application that was in my old board, i have on

Comment: @Robert It should be possible to use these files, yes. In particular you should be able to mount the rootfs some way. But it would be helpful if you gave us the output of `file` run on all of these files. Not yet sure if this information will suffice, but it will definitely get us further.

Comment: I'm counting five files you mentioned in your previous comment. Which one is ELF. What are the others? You can always also edit your question.

Comment: Could you please edit the information I asked into your question (`file` output for the five files above) ... for the ELF file we already know it's an ELF file, but you can also run `file` on it.

Comment: you have a lot of patience with me :)